# Knockout.js: Updation of label element not reflecting in JSON source

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am new to knockout.JS. I am binding a JSON collection to a table.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Collection">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="text: FirstName" ></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span data-bind="text: LastName" ></span> 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" data-bind="click: function(){ obj.RemoveItem($data) }" value="Del" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" data-bind="click: function(){ obj.SaveItems($data.Id) }" value="Edit/Save" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

function viewModel(collection) {
            var self = this;
            this.Collection = ko.observableArray(collection);
            this.AddItem = function() {
                this.Collection.push({FirstName:"", LastName:""});
            };
            this.RemoveItem = function(data) {
                this.Collection.remove(data);
            };
            this.SaveItems = function(id) {
                alert("New Collection: " + ko.utils.stringifyJson(self.Collection));
            }
        };

        var obj = new viewModel([
            { Id: 1,FirstName: "John", LastName: "Saleth" },
            { Id: 2, FirstName: "John", LastName: "Kennedy" }
        ]);

        ko.applyBindings(obj);
```

In eachrow, I kept a edit button which on click, inserts a textbox in all TD's with value of 
span. And on save click, i am updating the values of span elements with the values of textbox.

The problem is new values of span element is not reflecting in JSON collection. How to update the JSON source with updated span values on click of save button?

Answer (score 0):

You should make each property of the Collection array observable as well.

```
function ItemModel(item) {
    this.Id = ko.observable(item.Id);       
    this.FirstName = ko.observable(item.FirstName);
    this.LastName = ko.observable(item.LastName);     
};


function viewModel(collection) {
    var self = this;
    this.Collection = ko.observableArray();
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(collection, function (i) { self.Collection.push(new ItemModel(i));  });
    this.AddItem = function() {
        this.Collection.push(new ItemModel({
            FirstName: "",
            LastName: ""
        }));
    };
    ...
};
```